# Showing a different Notification Icon

Tags: android, xml, notifications, icons

I have an app that displays a picture of a smiley "notification" icon in the status bar. (That's the purpose of the app, just to show that smiley) and I'm wanting to make it so you can change the icon displayed in the settings. Here is my code for how the icon is displayed in the first place. As you can see I load it from a the drawable folder.

```
  @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//Smiley Notification Starts
NotificationManager nm=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification=new Notification(R.drawable.smiley_notification, "Smiley", System.currentTimeMillis());
Context context=MainActivity.this;
CharSequence title="Smiley Title";
CharSequence detail="Touch for more options";
Intent intent=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent  pending=PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, detail, pending);
nm.notify(0, notification);
//Smiley Notification Ends
```

And here is my Settings xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Additional Information" android:summary="More">
        <PreferenceScreen android:title="My Name" android:summary="Smiley Notification Developer">
            <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" android:data="http://instagram.com/AccountName" />
        </PreferenceScreen>
        <Preference
         android:title="Requests/Support"
         android:summary="Click here to email me">
<intent
  android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
  android:data="mailto:email@email.com?subject=Support*Smiley Lite">
  <extra android:name="android.intent.extra.TEXT" android:value="Enter your request or problem here with a brief description." />
</intent>
  </Preference>
        <PreferenceScreen android:title="More apps by provider" android:summary="Click here">
            <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" android:data="http://website.com" />
        </PreferenceScreen>
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

If you could tell me how I would go about adding like a checkbox to load a different icon(picture) that would be great. Thank you very much.

Comment: what have you tried that you are having problems with, we are not going to do it for you

Comment: I haven't tried anything, I don't know how I could make an icon appear from like clicking a checkbox or something in the settings page. I'm not asking for you guys to do it for me, I just need a direction to follow.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was forget the checkbox and manually make a button in the preferences.

Preferences.xml

```
<Preference android:title="Button Title"
                android:key=" button_id"
                android:summary="Button Description"/>
```

Then go to your preferences class and on the onCreate() method add

```
Preference button = (Preference)findPreference("button_id");
button.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) { 

                    //Add what you want it to do here

                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Just in case anyone comes through the same problem in the future (: